# Jquery onmouseover and onmouseout not appearing in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a new div and input within JQuery, when i use the following code in Firefox it works

jQuery("bracket div closebracket", { "class": "wrapper", id: "product" + i, "onmouseover": "javascript:Highlight('product" + i + "');", "onmouseout": "javascript:Lowlight('product" + i + "');" })
                    .append(jQuery("", { type: "text", id: "name" + i }))
                    .append(jQuery("", { type: "text", id: "property" + i }))
                    .appendTo("#someContainer");

I can see the onmouseover and onmouseout within Firebug, when looking at IE and Chrome the mouse actions aren't there, does anyone know why they don't work and how i'll be able to get that working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the syntax you are using to construct new elements. Try something like this instead:

```
$('<div></div>').addClass('foo').onclick(myFunction).appendTo(myContainer);
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn't work. I'm was using the following example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416227/create-dynamic-div-with-unique-ids-jquery

Comment: i've used the following,

'code'jQuery("<div class='wrapper' id='product" + i + "'  onmouseover='javascript:Highlight(this.id);' onmouseout='javascript:Lowlight(this.id);' ><input type='text' id='name" + i + "' /><input type='text' id='property" + i + "'  /></div>").appendTo("#someContainer");'code'