# how to add id attribute and unique id inside html div tag

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add id attribute and also unique id in the id attr. i tried but getting objects inside the id attribute

```js
$("div .abc").each(function() {
  $('.abc').attr('id', $(this).uniqueId());
})
```

```css
[id]::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="xyz">
  <div class="abc"></div>
  <div class="abc"></div>
  <div class="abc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `.uniqueId()`? Is that some jQuery add-on?

Comment: _"I want to add id attribute and also unique id in the id attr"_ - Why?

Comment: it will generate unique id see https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueid/

Comment: Oh oh, so yes, it's jQueryui, not jQuery.

Comment: I got this from here but not working i am new to jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/21038520/17023923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryUI `.uniqueId()` method does all the work you need internally. It returns a jQuery object, which is why you see what looks like an object. All you need in the `.each()` callback is

```
  $(this).uniqueId();
```

In fact you don't even need the `.each()`:

```
  $("div .abc").uniqueId();
```

will iterate through the matched elements and give each one a unique id value.

Answer (score 0):

yu can auto increment an id to an html element using either each loop or for loop

**each loop like this;**

```
$(".abc").each(function(i) {
  $(".abc").attr('id', 'id' + i);
})
```

**or using for loop**

```
for(var i = 0, i = $(".abc").length, i++){
  $(".abc").attr('id', 'id' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="xyz">
      <div class="abc"></div>
      <div class="abc"></div>
      <div class="abc"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(".abc").each(function (index) {
      $(this).attr("id", "abc" + index);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That does not *guarantee* uniqueness of "id" values.

Comment: It's your choice, if you want to use uuid4.

Comment: The point is that the `.uniqueId()` function the OP tried to use (incorrectly) **does** guarantee a unique id value for every affected element.

Comment: Please do not give additional information on your question in an answer. Instead, edit your question. I already did that for you in this case, so please delete this answer.