# Create Dynamic div with unique IDs - jQuery 3.4.1

Tags: html, jquery, dynamic

I'm using code from a previous question located at [Create Dynamic div with unique IDs - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416227/create-dynamic-div-with-unique-ids-jquery). The question when asked used jquery 1.4.2 but I am using jquery 3.4.1.

I changed the

`$("input").live("click", function() { $("span").text("Clicked ID: " + this.id);});`

to

`$("input").on("click", function() { $("span").text("Clicked ID: " + this.id);});`

But when you click on the input field now the text is not added to the span tag.

Here is my code on Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shammock3522/xyjwg4em/2/

Comment: Your code should not be behind a link. Please take some time to create a runnable snippet inside the question using the toolbar in the editor.

Comment: What you don't mention in your question is that the inputs are added after the event binding.  Change `$("input").on("click", function...` to `$(document).on("click", "input", function...`.  https://jsfiddle.net/9zjnf6y8/   Also, don't use dynamic IDs, you don't need them, it's the `name=` that's relevant and you already change that.

Comment: Thank you trincot for correcting me on the snippet and freedomn-m for the solution. The $(document).on works. I knew it was something simple.